# How do I access a MongoDB object id during creation?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, ref

I have a website where I want to do something like this:

```
myModel.create({myObject}); //I want to access the automatically created objectId of this new document
refModel.create({refId:somehowAccessId});
//Or, without Mongoose
db.myCollection.insert({myObject});
db.refCollection.insert({refId:somehowAccessId})
```

How is that done (preferably without using a `find` query and a callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose's `.save` for the purpose. Insert the object in the first model, save it, and upon receiving a success callback, use its `_id` for the second model,

```
let model = new myModel(myObject);
model.save(function(err, savedObject) {
   let accessId = savedObject._id;
   refModel.create({refId: accessId}); //or something similar
})
```

The same can be done without using mongoose

```
 db.myCollection.insert(objectToBeSaved, function(err, savedObject) {
   let accessId = savedObject._id;
   db.refCollection.insert({refId: accessId}); //or something similar
 })
```

Comment: I understand I can do that, but I am trying to avoid callbacks and excessive nesting. Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: If you don't want excessive nesting, you can try using `Promise`. That way you'll save yourself from callback hell, however, you can't access the `_id` without making sure the document has been created successfully and for that, you need to rely on a `callback` or `promise`.